# Breaking Down 3D models up to lines and curves

Tags: python, 3d, geometry, blender, openscad

I'm working on a project to breakdown 3D models but I'm quite lost. I hope you can help me.

I'm getting a 3D model from Autodesk BIM and the format could be native or generic CAD formats (.stp, .igs, .x_t, .stl). Then, I need to "measure" somehow the maximum dimensions to model a raw material body, it will always have the shape of a huge panel. Once I get both bodies, I will get the difference to extract the solids I need to analyze; and, on each of these bodies, I need to extract the faces, and then the lines or curves of each face.

This sounds something really easy to do on a CAD software, but the idea is to automate this process. I was looking into openSCAD, but seems that works only to model geometry and it doesn't handle well imported solids. I'm leaving a picture with the idea of what I need to do in the link below.

So, Any idea how can I do this? which langue and library can help in this project?

[image: General idea of the process]

Comment: You should look for those CAD formats so as to learn how they define a face, line, etc.

Comment: @ripi2 some of them define the solid as set of functions or operations on a primitive (like rotational surfaces are rotated bezier ... so not a mesh at all) something like hybrid between BR and Analytical representation... nice example for this is IGES ... I would go for STL as that is a set of triangles without holes and with complete connection between triangles without overlaps ... that can be converted into mesh surface topology .. matched to raw shape and substract .. using any constuctive geometry engine

Comment: How did you accomplish step C: extracting primitives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see this automation possible with a few in between steps:

1. OpenSCAD can handle differences well, so your "Extract Bodies" seems plausible

1.5 Before going further, you'll have to explain how you "filtered out" the cylinder. Will you do this manually? If you don't, you will have it considered for analysis and have a lot of faces as a result.

2. I don't think openSCAD provides you a vertex array. However, it can save to .STL, which is kinda easy to parse with the programming language of your choice, you'll have to study .stl file structure a bit (this sounds much more frightening than it is - if you open an stl with an editor you will probably immediately realize what's happening).

Since you've parsed the file, you can now calculate lines with high school math.

This is not an easy, GUI way to do what you ask, but if you have a few skills you'll have your automation, and depending on the amount of your projects it may be worth it.

Comment: Thanks for the guide. i'll try to check the stl structure. Any idea what would be the best to get it ? can I do that thru python or do I have to go thru C++?

Comment: I don't know python, but I'll wager the probability of you not being able to do it with python easily is astronomically small. Effectively these files are a header, a list of vertices, and a list of faces. Simple read commands will cover you.

Comment: Oh, the structure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll definitely look at this.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Do you have any suggestions for filtering out the primitives as in step 1.5?

Answer (score 0):

I have been working in this project, and foundt the library "trimesh" is better to solve this concern. Give it a shot, and save some time.